# Importing KML Google Maps files with custom data tables to QGIS?

Tags: qgis, kml, attribute-table

I am trying to visualize the complete attribute table of an exported Google Maps KML file with a customized data table, but QGIS 2.4.0 won't parse the added information correctly.

This is what I can read in the data in text format (1 line of the table):

```
 <name>Piante aliene Filipponi-Raniolo, Naviglio Pavese (zona 10)  06/06/2015</name>
    <description><![CDATA[]]></description>
    <Folder>
        <name>Livello senza titolo</name>
        <Placemark>
            <name>Marker 1</name>
            <description><![CDATA[Acer negundo: 1<br>Ailantus altissima: 1<br>Robinia pseudoacacia: 1<br>Parthenocissus quinquefolia: 1<br>Euforbia: 1<br>Acetosella: 1<br>Superficie verde/tot: 1]]></description>
            <styleUrl>#icon-503-DB4436</styleUrl>
            <ExtendedData>
                <Data name='Acer negundo'>
                    <value>1.0</value>
                </Data>
                <Data name='Ailantus altissima'>
                    <value>1.0</value>
                </Data>
                <Data name='Robinia pseudoacacia'>
                    <value>1.0</value>
                </Data>
                <Data name='Parthenocissus quinquefolia'>
                    <value>1.0</value>
                </Data>
                <Data name='Euforbia'>
                    <value>1.0</value>
                </Data>
                <Data name='Acetosella'>
                    <value>1.0</value>
                </Data>
                <Data name='Superficie verde/tot'>
                    <value>1.0</value>
                </Data>
            </ExtendedData>
            <Point>
                <coordinates>9.1735411,45.4334849,0.0</coordinates>
            </Point>
        </Placemark>
```

Right now, if I try to open the KML in QGIS directly, I only get the two default columns (name, description) with description containing all information.